# How to efficiently overwrite a variable value if present in configuration dictionary?

Tags: python, coding-efficiency

I have a simple piece of code that works, but I'd like to know if I can make it more Pythonic by using the dict.get() method.

```
chunk_size = 100000
if "chunk_size" in self.conf["source_config"]:
    chunk_size = self.conf["source_config"]["chunk_size"]
```

This overwrites the value for variable `chunk_size` with `self.conf["source_config"]["chunk_size"]`, but only if the key `chunk_size` is present in said configuration.

How can I make this more Pythonic?

Comment: use `get()` and supply default value if not present

Comment: `chunk_size = self.conf["source_config"].get("chunk_size", 100000)`

Comment: What is your problem with `dict.get` or with understanding it?

Comment: @MichaelButscher you don't **have** to reply lol

Comment: Thanks @ buran and @h4z3. I've combined your comments into a single answer. Feel free to edit and/or answer yourselves.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers of @h4z3 and @buran it appears to use .get() and use a default value. This looks like the following:

`chunk_size = self.conf["source_config"].get("chunk_size", 100000)`

Answer (score -2):

This is one possible way you might or might not have thought about;

```
chunk_size = 100000
conf = {}

chunk_size = conf["chunk_size"] if "chunk_size" in conf else chunk_size
```

This might be a little more pythonic than a full if clause?

Comment: How is it supposed not to crash?

Comment: @NikolajŠ in an expression like `x if cond else y`, x isn't evaluated if cond is False.

Comment: Can you elaborate? This is the same as OP but "more pythonic"... there are other ways, but this is not wrong...

the attribute is only accessed if it is present, so this should not crash at all...

Comment: @NikolajŠ. It won't crash but it isn't the Python-way at all (imho)

Comment: OP explicitely asked for a solution with `.get`?

Comment: @Klops, sorry, code snippet got cropped on the phone.  Still, it's no better than OP's version, and doesn't use `get()` as requested (and what is much more Pythonic)

Comment: ok, point taken, I missed `get()` requirement. Thanks for pointing this out.